# Do localhost routes work in live environments?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, routes

I have a project on localhost at the following route:

- http://127.0.0.1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/web/app_dev.php/signup

and I currently post data to the application from javascript like this:

```
// Centralised, referenced from each javascript file:
var baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/projects/PROJECT_NAME/web/app_dev.php';

// The signup post URL is generated like this:
var postUrl: baseUrl + "/signup",
```

This works for all files on localhost.

Questions:

- When this project goes live, do these URLs still work?
- Is there a cleaner way to write the baseUrl so that it doesn't need to change when the project goes live?

Apologies if this is an obvious one but I currently only work on localhost. Any suggestions welcome.
Symfony 3 application, XAMPP server, OSX.

EDIT:

Using $.ajax to make posts to server.

Comment: That'll depend entirely on the configuration of the production environment.

Comment: A. no. B have a config file with the base url in it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using to make your calls, `$.ajax()` accepts relative urls and [XMLHttpRequest.open()](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#request-url) doesn't specify that the url needs to be absolute, so I'd assume it can be relative as well so you could probably get away with relative urls and not worry about your environment

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest that you create a virtual host for your projects and set it's webroot to your project's web folder and access your project from there.

Here's a nice tutorial on how to do that in xampp for macOS:
http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2012/03/11/configuring-virtualhosts-in-xampp-on-mac/

i.e: `http://myproject.local`

This will allow you to access your URLS by simply writing `var postURL: "/signup"` which then will be treated as `http://myproject.local/signup` on your local environment or `http://myprojectlive.com/signup` on your live environment.

With that you'll save yourself a lot of configuration and coding troubles.

Answer (score 1):

When the project goes live the localhost URL absolutely will not work.

What you should do is have a build process that uses the localhost URL in development and inserts the production URL when the site is live.

Using Webpack, for example, you'd do something like this in development:

```
module.exports = {
  URL: '"http://127.0.0.1"'
}
```

And this in production:

```
module.exports = merge(devEnv, {
  URL: '"http://example.com"'
})
```

Then you'd then import that variable and probably assign it to something more concise and descriptive like so:

```
const baseUrl = process.env.URL
```

Having done this you can now use the variable wherever to make requests by concatenating it, for example, with a subdirectory like so:

```
`${baseUrl}/projects/PROJECT_NAME/web/app_dev.php`
```